# "é" become "ã©" while using ldap_modify_batch() in php

Tags: php, active-directory, character-encoding, ldap

I'm trying to update my Active Directory using php and the [ldap_modify_batch()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-modify-batch.php) function.
When I'm calling the function everything works fine, but sometimes, a user enters an accented character.
Therefore the edited field in my AD is not containing the accented character (like "é"), but it contain his equivalence in an other encoding standard(like "ã©").

Here is an exemple :

User input **-ldap_modify_batch()->** Result in my AD

"Comptabilité" **-ldap_modify_batch()->** "ComptabilitÃ©"

Here is the code for the specified arguments

```
$modifs = [
                    [
                        "attrib" => "telephoneNumber",
                        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REPLACE,
                        "values" => ["0123456789"],
                    ],
                    [
                        "attrib" => "mail",
                        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REPLACE,
                        "values" => ["amail@amail.com"],
                    ],
                    [
                        "attrib" => "description",
                        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REPLACE,
                        "values" => ["Comptabilité"],
                    ],
                    [
                        "attrib" => "physicalDeliveryOfficeName",
                        "modtype" => LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REPLACE,
                        "values" => ["AOfficName"],
                    ],
                ];
                ldap_modify_batch($connect, $dn, $modifs);
```

What should i do to bring the accents in my AD ?

Is there something i should change in my php.ini or elsewhere ?

Comment: You need to ensure you're using a consistent text encoding throughout, or intentionally converting from one encode to another as necessary. More: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html What you describe looks like the classic example fo UTF8 being rendered as though it were ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Thank you for you response, my input is already in UTF-8, but it seem's that  this function (**ldap_modify_batch()**) is encodying my input into ISO-8859-1, do you think it's possible ?

Comment: It seems possible, but I wouldn't know, I haven't used it. If so, you'd need to either tell it to use UTF8 (if possible), or convert the text from UTF8 to whatever it's using (ISO-8859-1 or whatever).

Comment: I find a solution, (but i don't know how to mark the topic as solved)..
So i've added a conversion to the ISO-8859-1 format to my input.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and explain how it works. Then, in a couple of days, you can accept that answer. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So, here is the solution we've founded :**

You must encode your string in "ISO-8859-1" instead of "UTF-8"
(I haven't any informations about why).

To encode your string you must use the php function **[iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.iconv.php)**

1. First parameter is the type of your original string
   (If you don't know what is your original encoding type you can use **[mb_detect_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)**  to get it.)
2. The second parameter has to be "ISO-8859-1"
3. The last parameter is the string you would like to convert.

Here is how i fixed my problem :

```
$office = "Comptabilité";
$value_ready_to_send = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($office),"ISO-8859-1",$office);
```